# argparse: parsing -h(some string here): changing default behavior

Tags: python, argparse

When I do the following:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args(['-ha'])
```

I get:

```
usage: [-h]
error: argument -h/--help: ignored explicit argument 'a'
```

**Note:** `-h` is run here and you get usage: `[-h]`.

but I want to get:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: -ha
```

without running `-h`.

I know that this is the default behavior of `argparse`, but I need to change that, and I was wondering if there is a workaround.

*I still want `-h` and `--help` to work.*

Comment: The default '-h' displays the help and exits.  It doesn't continue or make any use any other arguments.  What is the 'a' supposed to do?  Also the default behavior (well established) is to treat single character flags as 'chain-able'.

Comment: If you use `add_help=False` you can set your own help argument.

Comment: @hpaulj how am I gonna set a new help argument? Could you give me a reference please? this seems the only solution to my problem which is: not using -h/--help and setting them manually so they do not follow the default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this behavior has nothing to do with '-h' being help, but rather that is is a flag that takes 0 arguments:

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: parser.add_argument('-f', action='store_true')

In [4]: parser.parse_args(['-f'])
Out[4]: Namespace(f=True)
In [5]: parser.parse_args(['-fa'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f]
ipython3: error: argument -f: ignored explicit argument 'a'
```

This error is raised by the core function that processes short optionals.  '-f' is recognized as a short optional that takes 0 arguments.  So it can't be parsed as '-f a'.  And since '-a' has not been defined, it can't parse it as '-f -a'.

Here's an explicit way of define a help:

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
 parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help')
```

It behaves the same as the default, but can be customized, either with different flag strings, or a different `action`.  Writing a custom `action` class is more involved than I want get into now, but you can get ideas by looking at the `_HelpAction` subclass in the `argparse.py` file.

I was going to suggest making it `store_true` and doing the help processing after, but I already showed that `store_true` has this same problem with an extra string.

Your could try:

```
In [21]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
In [22]: parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', nargs='?', default=False, const=Tru
    ...: e);
In [23]: parser.parse_args(['-h'])
Out[23]: Namespace(help=True)
In [24]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[24]: Namespace(help=False)
In [25]: parser.parse_args(['-ha'])
Out[25]: Namespace(help='a')
In [26]: parser.parse_args(['-h','a'])
Out[26]: Namespace(help='a')
```

Comment: Yes I also tried that! it gives the same default behavior, is writing a custom action not a straight forward operation?

Comment: @hapulj Thank you very much, The last one worked perfectly, I read -h always as False and if it is provided, I check if it is alone or not and behave accordingly.

Comment: @hapulj when specifying -nargs, the usage message is different than the default, for example, if nargs="?", the usage message will be -h [metafvar], If nargs="*" the usage message will be -h [metavar [metavar [...]] ] . Although it worked but it breaks somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

`argparse` short form is ONE CHARACTER ONLY.

`-ah` is equivalent to `-h -a`.

If you want `ha` as single argument you mast use `--ha`

Comment: in that case -h would no longer be a disambiguous shortening of --help but i don't think there's a logical solution to this

Comment: '-ha' is a not a shortening of '--help'.

Comment: So I guess what I am doing here is anti-conventional to the library itself? am I right?

Comment: Yes if you want to treat `ha` as a single entity